# SWIFT how to copy nested struct element of super.array into array variable

Tags: arrays, swift, struct

sorry if this was already answered somewhere, I am not sure if I used the proper keywords in my search.

In order to pass an array to a function, I would like to pass the content of a stuct array to a variable. My struct looks basically like this (the content is a bit more complex in real)

```
struct topStruct: Codable {
   var topVar:[nestedStruct]
}

struct nestedStruct: Codable {
   var nestedVar:Int
}
```

Is there a more decent way to pass the value of nestedVar for all topVars to a function than this?

```
var myVar:topStruct!
var myVarArray:[Int]
for element in myVar.topVar {
   myVarArray[i] = element.nestedVar
   i=i+1
}
result = myFunc(myVarArray)
```

Or should I prefer to define myFunc as

```
myFunc(structPassed:topStruct!) -> Int {
   var result = 1
   for element in structPassed.topVar {
      result += element.nestedVar
      i=i+1
   }
return result
}
```

Since I do not need other elements from within nestedStruct (in the real life code) I guess the first approach is a bit leaner with regards to memory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest way is to use the high order function `map`

```
myFunc(myVar.topVar.map {$0.nestedVar})
```

If you haven't done so already it's time to learn about high order functions, they are really powerful tools when working with collections.

Comment: works like a charm. Will further look into "map". If you have another second, maybe you could also look into my other (unanswered) question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62692861/swift-issue-with-collaboration-of-view-from-storyboard-with-code-in-viewcontrol :-) Cheers (still on the steep part of the learning curve...)

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear what you want to do but I am writing correctly how you can fill an array:

```
var myVar: topStruct = topStruct(topVar: [nestedStruct(nestedVar: 1), nestedStruct(nestedVar: 2), nestedStruct(nestedVar: 3)])

var myVarArray = [Int]()
for element in myVar.topVar {
    myVarArray.append(element.nestedVar)
}
```

and how to return the sum of the elements in the array:

```
func myFunc(structPassed: topStruct) -> Int {
    var result = 0
    for element in structPassed.topVar {
      result += element.nestedVar
    }
    return result
}

myFunc(structPassed: myVar)
```